# Scala: How to merge the multiple CSV files in data frame

Tags: scala

I am writing the below code to get the csv file in RDD, I want to union multiple csv files and want to store in the single RDD variable. I am able to store the data of one csv file in RDD kindly help me how to union multiple csv files and to store in single RDD variable .

```
val Rdd = spark.sparkContext.textFile(“File1.csv").map(_.split(","))
```

I am expecting something like

```
 val Rdd = spark.sparkContext.textFile(“File1.csv").map(_.split(",")) union spark.sparkContext.textFile(“File2.csv").map(_.split(","))
```

Comment: What's wrong with your suggestion?

Comment: Thanks for your reply!!!Here I am hardcoding and limiting to only 2 files, I want to know what if multiple files comes. how to handle the scenario. And also I am not sure the file names it will come in dynamic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a large number of files I would suggest

```
val rdd = List("file1", "file2", "file3", "file4", "file5")
  .map(spark.sparkContext.textFile(_))
  .reduce(_ union _)
```

Or if you only know you have 0 or more files:

```
val rdd = getListOfFilenames()
  .map(spark.sparkContext.textFile(_))
  .foldLeft(spark.sparkContext.emptyRDD[String])(_ union _)
```

Comment: I am getting the below error with the above code,type mismatch; found : (String, Int) ⇒ org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String] required: String ⇒ ?

Comment: @Chandra I fixed it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick reply. Now I am saving the RDD to new csv file I am getting the error.  --                                                                                                          rdd.write.option("header", "true").mode("overwrite").csv(test1.csv") --                                                                                                value write is not a member of org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String]

Comment: That's a different unrelated issue.